# Error: Specified cast is not valid. when running a LINQ query

Tags: c#, sql-server

I am using the following code to pull in two data sets, one from a header table and one from a detail table.

```
String connectionString = "user id=####; password=####!; server=####; database=####";
        DataContext db = new DataContext
            (connectionString);
        Table<orderHeader> OrderHeader = db.GetTable<orderHeader>();
        Table<orderDetails> OrderDetails = db.GetTable<orderDetails>();
        List<clsOrders> orderexport = new List<clsOrders>();
        List<clsOrdersDetails> orderDetailexport = new List<clsOrdersDetails>();
        string custNumber;
        string custOrderNumber;
        IQueryable<orderHeader> ordqry =
            from ord in OrderHeader
            where ord.ORDERSTATUS == 1 || ord.ORDERSTATUS == 3
            select ord;

        foreach (var det in ordqry)
        {
            custNumber = det.CUSTNUM.ToString();
            custOrderNumber = det.ORDERNUMBER;

            IQueryable<orderDetails> orddetqry =                
            from orddet in OrderDetails
            where orddet.ORDERNUMBER == custOrderNumber                
            select orddet;
            foreach (var I in orddetqry)
            {
                clsOrdersDetails ordd = new clsOrdersDetails();
                ordd.itemNum = I.ITEMNUM;
                ordd.itemQty = I.ITEMQTY;
                orderDetailexport.Add(ordd);

            }


        }
    }

[Table(Name = "orderDetailsSurface")]
public class orderDetails
{
    private int _ItemSeq;
    [Column(IsPrimaryKey = true, Storage = "_ItemSeq")]
    public int ITEMSEQ
    {
        get
        {
            return this._ItemSeq;
        }
        set
        {
            this._ItemSeq = value;
        }

    }

    private string _ItemNum;
    [Column(Storage = "_ItemNum")]
    public string ITEMNUM
    {
        get
        {
            return this._ItemNum;
        }
        set
        {
            this._ItemNum = value;
        }
    }

    private string _ItemQty;
    [Column(Storage = "_ItemQty")]
    public string ITEMQTY
    {
        get
        {
            return this._ItemQty;
        }
        set
        {
            this._ItemQty = value;
        }
    }

    private int _ItemDesc;
    [Column(Storage = "_ItemDesc")]
    public int ITEMDESC
    {
        get
        {
            return this._ItemDesc;
        }
        set
        {
            this._ItemDesc = value;
        }
    }

    private string _ItemCost;
    [Column(Storage = "_ItemCost")]
    public string ITEMCOST
    {
        get
        {
            return this._ItemCost;
        }
        set
        {
            this._ItemCost = value;
        }
    }

    private string _ItemStatus;
    [Column(Storage = "_ItemStatus")]
    public string ITEMSTATUS
    {
        get
        {
            return this._ItemStatus;
        }
        set
        {
            this._ItemStatus = value;
        }
    }

    private string _OrderNumber;
    [Column(Storage = "_OrderNumber")]
    public string ORDERNUMBER
    {
        get
        {
            return this._OrderNumber;
        }
        set
        {
            this._OrderNumber = value;
        }
    }

}
```

I am getting the error in "foreach (var I in orddetqry)", I checked my db setup and my columns to make sure I am passing in the correct variable type.

I am not sure what is incorrect.

Edit: Added orderDetails class

Comment: Unfortunately you didn't include clsOrdersDetails and orderDetails. So I cannot be sure, but I think there is the possibility that somewhere ITEMNUM / ITEMQTY is null and itemNum / itemQty is not nullable.

Answer (score 0):

I found the issue, don't know why I didn't see it before. One of my public vars in the orderDetails class was set to an INT and it should have been a STRING.